# Obtaining styles from Selecteditem in ListView using DataTemplates

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to harvest data from a ListView but am having problems harvesting the data when it is coming from a DataTemplate.

```
//wpf code (basic)
<ListView x:Name="anotherList">
    <ListViewItem Tag="aTag" Content="A"/>
    <ListViewItem Tag="bTag" Content="B"/>
</ListView>
```

```
//c# code
// In order to access data in the ListView I would do this
ListViewItem selectedItem = (ListViewItem)anotherList.SelectedItem;
String selectedContent = selectedItem.Content;
```

Now when I try to include a DataTemplate in there, I cannot use the same method to access the data in wpf.

```
//wpf code using data template
<ListView x:Name="mainList">
    <ListView.ItemsSource>
        // Accessing data from an inline xml table
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource Book1}" XPath="Entry"/> 
    </ListView.ItemsSource>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListViewItem Tag="{Binding XPath=Tag}" Content="{Binding XPath=LastName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

```
//c# code
//gives null
var selectedItem = (ListViewItem)mainList.SelectedItem //....;
// throws exception
String selectedContent = selectedItem.Content;
```

Not sure how to proceed with the c# code since my selected item comes up as a whole string of XML content with no way to access content or tag. (i.e. it is showing up in the visual tree correctly but the ListViewItem is not behaving like a ListViewItem Object.) Is there a way to change my WPF code so that I can access the styles from the back like in the basic c# code?

Really appreciate the help and thanks for reading.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get at? You should be binding to actual *objects* (including `SelectedItem`) not the UI controls.

Comment: Is the DataTemplate only modifying the UI? How do I go about binding my properties to the actual object?

Comment: Sounds like you should go through an MVVM tutorial: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msgulfcommunity/2013/03/13/understanding-the-basics-of-mvvm-design-pattern/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This aproach based on MVVM works for me

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MyViewModel}">
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <Grid d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:User}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private User _selectedUser;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Users = new ObservableCollection<User>
        {
            new User{FirstName = "User A FirstName", LastName = "User A LastName"},
            new User{FirstName = "User B FirstName", LastName = "User B LastName"},
            new User{FirstName = "User C FirstName", LastName = "User C LastName"}
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    public User SelectedUser
    {
        get { return _selectedUser; }
        set
        {
            _selectedUser = value;
            Debug.WriteLine(_selectedUser.LastName);
        }
    }
}

public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

DataContext binding:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is the first MVVM I have seen that I can actually understand without commentary, since it relates directly to my problem. I will have to try it out later.